# Find multiple matches of this and that nucleotide sequence

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics

I want find every incident of ATG...TAG or ATG...TAA. I have tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $file = ('ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAGATGAAAAAAAAAATAAATGAAAAATAGATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC');

while($file =~ /((?=(ATG\w+?TAG|ATG\w+?TAA))/g){ 
    print "$1\n";           
}
```

which gives-

```
ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAG
ATGAAAAAAAAAATAAATGAAAAATAG
ATGAAAAATAG
```

I want -

```
ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAG
ATGAAAAAAAAAATAA
ATGAAAAATAG
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for one or the other, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually very close, it appears from your statement above that you have *two* captures, when I think you really only want a single one; I also don't think you need the lookahead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = ('ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAGATGAAAAAAAAAATAAATGAAAAATAGATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC');

while($file =~ /(ATG\w+?TA[AG])/g){
    print "$1\n";
}

# output
# ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAG
# ATGAAAAAAAAAATAA
# ATGAAAAATAG
```

Line by line:

> ATG  matches a literal *ATG*
>
> \w+? optionally matches *one or more* characters
>
> TA[AG] matches a literal *TAA* or *TAG*

Answer (score 1):

`/(ATG\w+?TA[AG])/` works and is a bit more elegant than what `FlyingFrog` proposed ;-)

```
-bash-3.2$ perl
my $string = 'ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAGATGAAAAAAAAAATAAATGAAAAATAGATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC';
my @matches = $string =~ /(ATG\w+?TA[AG])/g;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@matches;
$VAR1 = [
          'ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAG',
          'ATGAAAAAAAAAATAA',
          'ATGAAAAATAG'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will find sequences starting with `ATG` and ending in `TAG` or `TAA` - whichever comes first. If you removed all the `TAG`s from your sequence, you would find the stretches that end in `TAA`. By making two capture groups (one for `ATG...TAG` and one for `ATG...TAA`) you will find all sequences.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $file = ('ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAGATGAAAAAAAAAATAAATGAAAAATAGATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC');

while($file =~ /(?=(ATG\w+?TAG))(?=(ATG\w+?TAA))/g){ # makes two capture groups 
    print "$1\n";
    print "$2\n";           
}
```

Output:

```
ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAG
ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAGATGAAAAAAAAAATAA
ATGAAAAAAAAAATAAATGAAAAATAG
ATGAAAAAAAAAATAA
```

---- OR: ----

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $file = ('ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAGATGAAAAAAAAAATAAATGAAAAATAGATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC');

while($file =~ /(?=(ATG\w+?TA[AG]))/g){ 
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAG
ATGAAAAAAAAAATAA
ATGAAAAATAG
```

Depending on what exactly you're after...

Comment: The second one does what I want it