# For a set of sequences store sequence in hash and its open reading frames as values

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, hash, bioinformatics

As follow up to ([Find multiple matches of this and that nucleotide sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593776/find-multiple-matches-of-this-and-that-nucleotide-sequence))

I now want to add each ORF (as by ATG...TAG or ATG...TAA) into a hash for each sequence so that for any sequence I have ORFs attached as values. I have so far -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @file = qw(ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAGATGAAAAAAAAAATAAATGAAAAATAGATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC ATGCGCGCTATATATGCGCGGGCTAATATAT ATATGAGGTCGTAGCTAGCAAACACAAATAAA );

my %hash;
foreach (@file){
my @match = ($_ =~ /(ATG\w+?TA[AG])/g);

# then make %hash with sequence as key and ORFs as values)...

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried a hash of arrays - to hold multiple 'match' values?

Comment: yeah - but is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on your code: (I've changed the nucleotide sequence to make it easier to see the stop and start codons, but but will work exactly the same way for your sequences...) I've also stored your matched sequences in a array within a hash of arrays as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @file = qw(ATGcgcgcgcgcgcgTAAATGatatatatataTAG ATGcccccccccTAAgggggggggATGtttttttttttTAG atATGaggggaTAGaaaatttttttctttct);

my (@match, %hash, @sequence, $line);
my $line_number = 0;
foreach  (@file){
    push @match, /(ATG\w+?TA[AG])/g;    
    push @sequence, @file for 0 .. $#match; 
}

push @ { $hash{$sequence[$_]}}, [$match[$_] ] for 0 .. $#match; # Hasho of arrays

for my $key (sort keys %hash){
        for my $orf (@ { $hash{$key}}){
            my ($match) = @$orf;
            print "Sequence:$key contains ORFs: $match\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sequence:ATGcccccccccTAAgggggggggATGtttttttttttTAG contains ORFs: ATGatatatatataTAG
Sequence:ATGcccccccccTAAgggggggggATGtttttttttttTAG contains ORFs: ATGaggggaTAG
Sequence:ATGcgcgcgcgcgcgTAAATGatatatatataTAG contains ORFs: ATGcgcgcgcgcgcgTAA
Sequence:ATGcgcgcgcgcgcgTAAATGatatatatataTAG contains ORFs: ATGtttttttttttTAG
Sequence:atATGaggggaTAGaaaatttttttctttct contains ORFs: ATGcccccccccTAA
```